# Blender physics not interacting properly

Tags: physics

I'm trying to create a conveyer belt like scene in blender using ecospheres. In the scene, icospheres are dropped onto the conveyer belt and carried out of scene, however the 3rd icospheres will not move with the conveyer belt properly.

File:
https://blend-exchange.com/b/Ps0q04s6/

Comment: Here is the file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=Ps0q04s6" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Ps0q04s6/)

Comment: You can directly paste the link into your question, by editing it. It will show a nice symbol. Apart from that, I only see squishy spheres being dropped onto the belt and no problem at that

Comment: what makes you think that the simulation is not ok?

Comment: The first two spheres drop and roll move along with the conveyer belt well, however the the third icosphere does not move along. It lands and simulates the landing, however it does not move along and offscreen like the other two spheres. This is important as I am trying to loop it. Any recommendations on how I could achieve this or what I may be doing wrong? @WhatAMesh

Comment: I am trying to loop the animation, so I need all of the icospheres to interact with the environment the sam way. The third icosphere that drops does not move along like the other two. It's probably just a simple error, however it's still annoying and I have not yet been able to figure what I am doing wrong.. @Chris